# Making services in Tapestry 5: No service implements the interface

Tags: maven, service, interface, tapestry

I'm developing my first Tapestry application with a login system based on a Hibernate database.

On one page with a session object, I want to call my `Authenticator` service class, which also gets the session injected and does some stuff. My problem is, I can't get any services to run, it's been very frustrating, despite me following simple guides like this one: http://code.google.com/p/shams/wiki/Service

In my `services` package, I got the `Authenticator.java` and `AuthenticatorImpl.java` interface and implemented class. In the `AppModule` class, I call

```
    binder.bind(Authenticator.class, AuthenticatorImpl.class);
```

And in my page 'ShowAllUsers' I inject my Authenticator service object:

```
...
public class ShowAllUsers{
@Inject
private Session session;

@Inject
private Authenticator authenticator;
...
}
```

But when I load the page on my server, I receive following error:

```
org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationException
Error obtaining injected value for field de.webtech2.pages.user.ShowAllUsers.authenticator: No service implements the interface de.webtech2.services.Authenticator.

trace:
- Creating instantiator for component class de.webtech2.pages.user.ShowAllUsers
- Running component class transformations on de.webtech2.pages.user.ShowAllUsers
- Injecting field de.webtech2.pages.user.ShowAllUsers.authenticator
```

But my AppModule does bind the class to the interface successfully. In the Maven build console I can read "Authenticator: DEFINED" and if I try to bind it in another module, it complains because it's bound in AppMopule already.

Why doesn't tapestry see the implementation? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you imported a different Authenticator from the wrong package in your AppModule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't solved the issue itself but I found a workaround that fixes it. As you might find on the internet, Tapestry allows for auto-reloading classes. Pages and components do work fine, services have some limitations -- this is where there seem to arise issues. Tomcat doesn't link the interface to the implementation.

Fix: A simple restart of eclipse solves this. Meh.
(This also fixes the "method not found" error if you added a new method to an existing service)

Also, when I execute `mvn clean`, everything gets screwed many times over. Eclipse can no longer resolve the simplest class and package references. Classes in the same package can no longer be found, or references to the javax.internet package lead into eternal nothingness -- whereas everything was working just fine a moment ago.

Fix:

```
Right-click eclipse project -> Properties -> Maven
```

Tick the checkbox for "**Resolve dependencies from Workspace projects**" and hit **Apply**.
If it is already checked, uncheck -> apply, then recheck -> apply. Eclipse should go sane again -- until next time...

Answer (score 0):

Glad you checked the startup log output, that's certainly the first "sanity check" towards addressing this problem.

I think uklance has the right idea: do a clean build, make sure you don't have multiple classes named Authenticator floating around ... perhaps from a 3rd party library.  I'm always having problems where I accidentally import a non-Tapestry class that happens to be named "Resource" or something.

Comment: My class references are correct. At some point Tomcat decided to magically find the "missing" class, although I haven't changed a thing.
My development setup is frustratingly moody. At times my services don't work at all, the next day everything is fine. If Tomcat complains about "no such method found" in newly written service methods, I restart eclipse. But I can't find a pattern to fix those "no implementation" found issues. Eclipse also likes to pretend some classes in packages don't exist at all. Those issues come and go at random. I think Tapestry is a nice thing, but this is just awful.